# MVC 4.6 Binding a drop down from dbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I have an mvc empty project where I'm trying to pull questions from the database based on what a user select from a title drop down (The values for the dropdown also come from the database).
I have the drop down working with hard coded values so far. How can I pull the titles from the database and how can I pull the questions associated with the title selected.

The auto generated model I have looks like this

```
namespace Demo1.Models{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public partial class Title
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Title()
    {
        TitlesQuestions = new HashSet<TitlesQuestion>();
    }

    public int TitleId { get; set; }

    [Column("Title")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Title1 { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TitlesQuestion> TitlesQuestions { get; set; }
    public SelectList TitleList { get; set; }

}
```

My ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Demo1.ViewModels.Titles
{
    public class TitlesViewModel
    {
        public int TitleId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
using Demo1.Models;
using Demo1.ViewModels.Titles;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Demo1.Controllers
{
    public class TitlesController : Controller
    {
        private EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
        public IEnumerable<Title> GetTitleList()
        {
            var result = db.Titles.ToList();

            return result;
        }
        // GET: Titles
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var titles = GetAllTitles();
            var model = new TitlesViewModel();
            model.Titles = GetSelectListItems(titles);

            return View(model);
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetAllTitles()
        {
            return new List<string>
            {
                "CEO",
                "Project Manager",
                "Technical Lead",
                "Software Developer",
            };
        }

        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
        {
            var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = element,
                    Text = element
                });
            }

            return selectList;
        }
    }
}
```

My View

```
@model Demo1.ViewModels.Titles.TitlesViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Questions by Title Demo</h2>
<form asp-controller="Titles" asp-action="Index" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <label asp-for="Title" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, // 1. Store selected value in Model.Roles when page is rendered after postback,take selected value from Model.State.
            Model.Titles, // 2. Take list of values from Model.Titles
            "- Please select your title -", // 3. Text for the first 'default' option
            new { @class = "form-control" }) @*// 4. A class name to assign to <select> tag*@
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use your dbContext in your `GetSelectListItems` method, instead of the `elements`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using entity framework
    private EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
I have a table named Titles

Here's my new ActionResult Index()

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TitlesViewModel();
        var titles = GetSelectListItems();
        model.Titles = titles;

        return View(model);
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems()
    {
        foreach (var title in db.Titles)
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = title.TitleId.ToString(),
                Text = title.Title1
            };
        }
    }
```

When I try to run my project I get the following error 
The class 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' has no parameterless constructor. I'm new to mvc so I'm not sure how to fix it. This seems like it should be a simple task I'm trying to bind data from the titles table to a drop down then once a title is selected I want the relevant questions from the database to show.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a question that involves on how to query a database. Overall this question needs alittle more context (what database is being used). Depending on what you're using there are many ways to query a database. My favorite for SQL is using [ADO.NET Entity Data Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.100).aspx). This is a database first approach. It creates a .edmx that creates all the models from the tables you select when setting it up.

After Setup:

Access data entities

```
MyAccountEntities users = new MyAccountEntities();
```

Access tables(use LINQ to change `DbSet<UserAccount>` to `List<UserAccount>`) ;)

```
users.UserAccounts.ToList();
```

Use LINQ to query your table/list. (returns a list of users named bob)

```
string username = "bob";
users.UserAccounts.Where(u => u.username == username).ToList();
```

UPDATE!!!!

Thank you for narrowing your problem down. The problem is pretty straight-forward. You have no constructor that takes parameters for your SelectListItem model. Go to where the model is defined then create a constructor with the parameters you wish to pass it.

Hope this Helps. Cheers :)

Comment: if any questions, ask away.